# Retrieve clusters with > n members from hierarchical clustering

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I am performing hierarchical clustering on a Doc2Vec model of around 15,000 docs with 90 dimensions.

While using SciPy's fcluster function to retrieve flat cluster is somewhat useful, it yields some clusters with either too few members (>1% of docs) or too many (<45%) to be informative because of the significant discrepancy between cluster sizes at the same distance level.

Here is an example of what my data looks like with a truncated dendrogram containing the first 100 linkages:

[image: Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram]

(Notice the significant discrepancy between cluster sizes on the different leaves on the x axis)

My code to produce this dendrogram and retrieve flat clusters is the following:

```
dm = pdist(X, 'cosine') # X is the array containing doc vectors
method = 'average'
Z = linkage(dm, method=method, metric='cosine', optimal_ordering=False)

def fancy_dendrogram(*args, **kwargs):
    max_d = kwargs.pop('max_d', None)
    if max_d and 'color_threshold' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['color_threshold'] = max_d
    annotate_above = kwargs.pop('annotate_above', 0)

    ddata = dendrogram(*args, **kwargs)

    if not kwargs.get('no_plot', False):
        plt.title('Truncated Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram (method = %s)'%method)
        plt.xlabel('sample index or (cluster size)')
        plt.ylabel('distance')
        for i, d, c in zip(ddata['icoord'], ddata['dcoord'], ddata['color_list']):
            x = 0.5 * sum(i[1:3])
            y = d[1]
            if y > annotate_above:
                plt.plot(x, y, 'o', c=c)
                plt.annotate("%.3g" % y, (x, y), xytext=(0, -5),
                             textcoords='offset points',
                             va='top', ha='center')

        if max_d:
            plt.axhline(y=max_d, c='k')
    return ddata

fancy_dendrogram(
    Z,
    color_threshold=0.94,
    truncate_mode='lastp',
    p=100,
    leaf_rotation=90.,
    leaf_font_size=12.,
    show_contracted=True,
    annotate_above=0,  # useful in small plots so annotations don't overlap
    max_d=None
)

plt.show()

print(colored("\n Choose your method for flat cluster retrieval.\n", "green"))
method = input(colored("Number or distance? "))

if method == "number":
  k = input("Enter the number of clusters to retrieve: ")
  cluster = fcluster(Z, k, criterion='maxclust')

if method == "distance":
  max_d = input("Enter the distance cutoff: ")
  cluster = fcluster(Z, max_d, criterion='distance')
```

What I would like to do is walk down the leaves of the dendrogram and stop to retrieve clusters that have less than *n* members (e.g., 30% of the corpus) and more than *m* members (e.g., 5% of the corpus), so that each cluster has a size that lends itself to better human interpretability.

How could I do that? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't process the dendrogram. Process Z. This should be an O(n) operation on Z.

Comment: @Paul Miller Did you find an answer to your question? I have a similar problem where I need to find the number of clusters based on a limit on the number of nodes in each cluster.